# Computing Spectrum of Linear Differential Operator non-constant Coefficients

Tags: operator-theory, spectral-theory, eigenfunctions

I am trying to solve directly (numerically if direct methods are not possible) for the spectrum of the differential operator
\begin{align*}
   & \mathscr{L}v \equiv (D\partial_{\xi\xi} -c \partial_{\xi} + J(\xi))v \newline
   & v(0) = v(1)
\end{align*}

where $\xi \in [0, 1]$, $v:[0, 1] \mapsto \mathbb{R}^n$ is a vector function, $D \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is a diagonal matrix with non-negative entries (i.e. it's non necessarily invertible), $c \in \mathbb{R}$, and $J: [0, 1] \mapsto \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is smooth on $[0, 1]$.

Is there an elegant way of solving for the spectrum? I'm able to estimate it using finite differencing, however for certain $J(\xi)$, the eigenvalues $\lambda$'s are either too inaccurate, or certain (important for my problem) eigenvalues are missing from the approximate spectrum.

Any references/solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should edit the question and add more details. Is $\xi\in\mathbb [0,1]$? What are the domain and codomain of $v$, $J$? What are the properties of the function $J$ one can assume? I can maybe deduce them from what you wrote, but people should be able to understand easily what you are asking.

Comment: @LorenzoPompili I added more context, lmk if you need more

Comment: It looks much better. Unfortunately I don't have an answer though. Can I ask another thing: does $J$ satisfy $J(0)=J(1)$ as well (and is it smooth if extended by periodicity for all $\xi\in\mathbb R$)?